# How can I make the vertical space to be of the same length as the horizontal space when creating a photo grid collage with Contact Sheet in Photoshop?

Tags: adobe-photoshop, automation, grids

I use Photoshop -> File -> Automate -> Contact Sheet II to create a photo grid collage. The vertical spaces are much larger than the horizontal spaces:

[image]

How can I make the vertical spaces to be of the same length as the horizontal spaces, when creating a photo grid collage with Contact Sheet II in Photoshop?

---

Contact Sheet II settings:

[image]

[image]

---

Images used:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Images need to be **promotional** if you wish them to have the same gutter. Contact sheet **won't** "stretch" images vertically to keep a gutter dimension.

Comment: @Scott thanks, sorry what is a promotional image? I googled it a bit and didn't see a definition. I was hoping the contact sheet could organize images of same size so that the horizontal spacing between images is the same as the vertical space between images

Comment: ehh. sorry... auto fill.. I meant *proportional*. And Contact Sheet is filling your predetermined 8x10 sheet with as many images as it can fit.. not varying the sheet dimensions in order to keep gutters *and* images the same size.

Comment: @Scott got it. The images are proportional as they have the same size. I was hoping there was some parameter same would specify: keep vertical and horizontal spacing the same (assuming images are proportional).

Comment: Proportional does not mean "same size". It's mean each of your 6 images, vertically, need to fill the space available once (0.014" * 10) is subtracted from your sheet height - 10". So [ 10 - (0.014 *10) /  6 = 1.643" ] -- Each of the images needs to be 1.64" in height to maintain your desired gutter and use 10" vertically.

Comment: @Scott thanks, got it. I  was hoping  Contact Sheet II had an option to "push" the unused vertical space to the margin of the main image, and not in-between the inserted small images.

Comment: Math is wonky in that comment above.. overcompensated for the gutters.. it's better in the actual answer `:)`

Comment: @Scott at least you did the math :) I simply tried a few values

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Contact sheet will not "Stretch" images to fill spaces.

If you wish all gutters to be the same, one needs to do the math and figure out the proper image size to fit the desired sheet size.

This means each of your 6 images, vertically, need to fill the space available once the gutter has been accounted for. So ...

```
10" / 6 = 1.666" minus gutter (0.014) = 1.652"
```

And you can do the same for the horizontal...

```
8" / 4 = 2 minus gutter (0.014) = 1.986"
```

Each of the images needs to be `1.986" x 1.652"` in size to maintain your desired gutter and use an 8" x 10" sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Contact Sheet II chooses vertical spacing so that the images are vertically spread across the document. As a result, one can reduce the  image height to reduce the vertical spacing, e.g. from 10 inches to 9.5 inches in this example:

[image]

The vertical spacing is now more similar to the horizontal spacing:

[image]

One could compute which height results in the vertical spacing being equal to the horizontal spacing. Or just say empirical and try a few values.